# action callback for libnotify not working

Tags: python, ubuntu, linux-mint, libnotify

I am trying to develop a desktop notification system with python and Libnotify.

I found this [tutorial](http://www.devdungeon.com/content/desktop-notifications-python-libnotify) and tried the example with an action callback, below is my code modification

```
#initialization of libnotify
Notify.init("Py-Notification")

#creating object
summary = "Wake Up!"
body = "Meeting at 9pm"
notification = Notify.Notification.new(
    summary, body
)    

# Define a callback function
def my_callback_func():
    webbrowser.open('http://google.com')

#adding actions
notification.add_action(
    "action_click",
    "Reply to Alarm",
    my_callback_func,
    None # Arguments
)   

notification.show()
```

The callback function is not called whenever I click on the "Reply to Alarm" button

Any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to integrate with D BUS to receive events from your notifications.

[Here is good explanation use Glib for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681532/python-program-with-notification-in-gnome-shell-doesnt-work/32839296#32839296).

Comment: this worked, but I had to comment out the line #GLib.timeout_add_seconds(10, self.check). this line kept sending the notificaiton.